# Informatica-Cloud: How do I use two source files with different structure in a single mapping?

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

How do I use two source files with different structure in a single mapping. There are no common columns.
If there are relational tables with some common columns we can use JOINER but how do we handle here?

Comment: You can use joiner for flat file source too. But you said there are no common columns. Can you union them ? If yes then you can union them but you need to make sure you pick up columns with same data type. You have two separate targets then you dont need anything and the files can be loaded into their corresponding target. If you give more details then i can be of more help.

Comment: Can you put an example here with full description?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I resolved the issue. As there are two different source file with no common columns and datatype so we take two expression , one each for the source file and then in both the expressions we create a dummy output port and assign value '1'. Using these two ports we can join the files in the next step using Joiner.